# How to use ngrok with hosts file (laradock)

Tags: ngrok, laradock

I am using Laradock to develop locally and so have an entry in the hosts file.

How can I get this working with ngrok?

I tried:

```
ngrok http -host-header=site.test 80
```

(https://helgesverre.com/blog/expose-local-webserver/)

but get: `Failed to complete tunnel connection`

(site.test works)

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by running ngrok on the host machine instead of the container.